# Login form using react js and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, authentication

I am building a login form using JSON data. Code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
class Login extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}
onSubmit() {
    fetch('http://xyz/check-login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: 'abc@abc.com',
            password: '123456',
        })
    })
}
<form name="Login">
<div className="text-left">
<div className="row">
<div className="col-12"><Input placeholder="Email Id" className="form-control"/></div>
</div>
<div className="row">
<div className="col-12"><Input placeholder="Password" type="password" className="form-control m-b-10"/></div>
</div>

<Button type="button" className="m-t-20 orange" label="Sign in " onClick={this.onSubmit} /> 
</form>
```

But its giving following error:

> Fetch API cannot load http://xyz/check-login. Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Is this the correct method to do?

<sub>I am very new to react</sub>

Comment: Your question doesn't really have to do with React, but the `fetch` API. The method looks fine, but the response seems to show that the server is not setup to accept that header (content-type).

Comment: @Ursus Thanks for your reply. Can you also give some solution for this?

Comment: Either try without the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` header, or change the serverside API so that it accepts that header.

Comment: @FabianSchultz Thanks. It worked for me.